# Getting Authentication Error when trying to connect search engine using Core Service

Tags: 2013, core-service, search-engine

I am getting error "**Sending a request to the Search Engine at http://localhost:8983/tridion failed with the following response: The connection can not be authenticated.**" while executing the following code:

SearchQueryData filter = new SearchQueryData();
filter.Author = new LinkToUserData() { IdRef = "tcm:0-11-65552" };
filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component,ItemType.Page};
XElement results = client.GetSearchResultsXml(filter);

I have checked the User is added to the SDLSearchUsers group and same has been configured in MMC Settings.

Please find below the code block along with connection to core service

ChannelFactory factory = new ChannelFactory("basicHttp_2013")

NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("Username", "password", "domain");
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = networkCredential;

ICoreService client = factory.CreateChannel();

SearchQueryData filter = new SearchQueryData();
filter.FullTextQuery = "Home";
IdentifiableObjectData[] resultSearchData = client.GetSearchResults(filter);

Answer (score 1):

have you tried just using your browser to hit the solr engine and log in as your user to make sure you can connect?

Comment: When I am trying to access http://localhost:8983/tridion using configured user, getting error as "HTTP Status 404 - /tridion

type Status report

message /tridion

description The requested resource is not available."

Comment: try using /#/tridion instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. From server when I try to access http://localhost:8983/#/tridion I get a Solr Dashboard page. Then did change the Tridion MMC setting and ran the application. Now this time I am getting following error "Error occured while processing the request: Not Found. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

Comment: I don't understand what (or why) you changed in MMC. can you edit your question and show the whole solution? seems like something simple is not set up correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I changed both Indexer and Query Engine host URL to http://localhost:8983/#/tridion and code block of the search is already provided in the question.

Comment: you aren't showing how you are connecting to your core service. perhaps that's your issue?

Comment: apology for not providing the entire code block at first option. I have edited my question there provided the code block along with connecting to my core service.

Comment: Warner Thanks for all clues. Now I have solved the problem and it was not in code rather in search settings in Tridion CMS. Once again thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of the question and some of the comments as well as your comment about changing the Indexer and Query Engine, it sounds like http://localhost:8983/tridion is a location of SOLR. What is the ip:port that Tridion CM is running on.

The code you provided is indeed for CoreServices and should be directed to Tridion and not SOLR. Your application should point to an endpoint something similar to

> http://localhost:82/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/basicHttp
>
> or
>
> http://localhost:82/webservices/CoreService2013.svc/wsHttp

replacing 82 with the port on which the Tridion CM is running on.